# Kill() error: no such process?

Tags: c, process, signals, posix, kill

I have to insert an odd number by terminal. After this, it generates two processes, A and B.
Then it sends `SIGUSR2` signal to B, and his handler prints the reciprocal of the `argv[1]`. Then, B sleeps for `argv[1]` seconds and sends `SIGUSR1` signal to A process before terminating. The `SIGUSR1` handler for process A prints something and then terminates.
The problem is that `SIGUSR1` handler for process A doesnt' work because the signal couldn't be sent by `SIGUSR2` handler for process B. In fact, the `kill(A,SIGUSR1)` tells that there is no such process (for process A). After setting the signal handler in process A, it is in `pause()`. 
Can anyone help me to solve? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int arg;
int pid1 = 11, pid2 = 12;

void sigusr2Handler1(int);
void sigusr1Handler2(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s num(int)\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    pid1 = fork();    
    if (pid1 != 0)     
        pid2 = fork();
    if (arg%2 != 0) {
        if (pid1 == 0) {
            if (signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1Handler2) == SIG_ERR) {
                printf("PID %d can't catch SIGUSR1\n", getpid());
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("PID1 %d sigusr1 handler2 installation\n", getpid());
            pause();
        }
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            signal(SIGUSR2, sigusr2Handler1);
            printf("PID2 %d sigusr2 handler installation\n", getpid());
            kill(0, SIGUSR2);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void sigusr2Handler1(int sig)
{
    printf("PID %d Received SIGUSR2. 1/%d = %f.\n", getpid(), arg, (float)1 / arg);
    sleep(arg);
    if (kill(pid1, SIGUSR1) < 0) {
        perror("Kill error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("PID %d. Sent SIGUSR1 to %d. Closing\n", getpid(), pid1);
    exit(0);
}

void sigusr1Handler2(int sig)
{
    printf("PID %d Received SIGUSR1. Closing.\n", getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*pid1* has been killed by the time *pid2* attempts to send a it a SIGUSR1.  *pid2* is the killer.

When *pid2* issues a `kill(0, SIGUSR2),` this sends SIGUSR2 [to the entire process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html), including *pid1*.  This kills *pid1*, which is unprepared to receive a SIGUSR2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought that it was right. I correct it into kill(getpid(),SIGUSR2 and now it works fine. But, if I make from the father process kill(pid2,SIGUSR2), it doesn't work again. How can I send the signal from the father to the process B?